# jquery : how to show the next div and hide the present one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to hide the present div and show next hide
here is my codes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#next').click(function() {
    $(this).next().next().children("div").hide();
    $(this).next().next().children("div").show();
  });
});
```

```css
#div2,
#div3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
<hr />
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
  <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
  <div id="div3">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

​**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/Qw75j/3/)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qw75j/7/).
Handles start/end using `css` classes, kept `js` simple.

Comment: The Divs are auto generated using a loop using XSLT and no way to add first or last as class. Any help on that?

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

  var currentDiv = 0;
  $('#next').click(function() {
    $('#div' + (currentDiv + 1)).hide();
    currentDiv = (currentDiv + 1) % 3;
    $('#div' + (currentDiv + 1)).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: would be better without the global, this also assumes the `#main` div will always only have 3 children... i suggest making `% 3` dynamic

Comment: @JohnnyCraig: yep, could easily put `$('#div1').parent().children('div').length` in there, or `$('#div1').siblings('div').length + 1`

Answer (score 2):

try something a little different

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#next').click(function() {
          $eL=$('#main').children('div').filter(":visible");
          $('#main').children().hide();
          if($eL.next().length>0){
              $eL.next().show();
          }else{
               $('#main div')[0].show();
          }

    });

    $('#prev').click(function() {
          $eL=$('#main').children('div').filter(":visible");
          $('#main').children().hide();
          if($eL.previous().length>0){
              $eL.previous().show();
          }else{
               $('#main div')[$('#main div').length - 1].show();
          }

    });

});
```

edit: this function assumes one of the child divs is already visible when the page loads.

edit: added for previous button

Comment: I have something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/st8q8z5g/3/ The previous isn't working and Next works except, how can I modify it so the it cycles through if it is the last one or the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (next and previous handled):

```
.item{
    display:none;
}​


var activeItem = 0;

function switchItem(isNext) {

        if (isNext) {
            activeItem++;
        } else {
            activeItem--;
        }

        activeItem = (activeItem == 3) ? 0 : activeItem;
        activeItem = (activeItem == -1) ? 2 : activeItem;

        showItem($("#main"), activeItem);
    }


    function showItem(selector, index) {

        selector.find(".item").hide().eq(index).toggle();
    }

<div id="main">   
    <div id="div1" class="item">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="item">Div 2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="item">Div 3</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: You could also use `activeItem = (activeItem + 3) % 3;`, just to simplify a little bit ;) or even `activeItem = (activeItem + (isNext ? 1 : -1) + 3) % 3;`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code.

```
<ul class="grid">
   <li class="object">
     List Item 1<a class="show-next"> Show the next list item</a>
   </li>
        <li class="object">
     List Item 2
     <a class="show-next">Show the next list item</a>
   </li>
        <li class="object">
     List Item 3
     <a class="show-next">Show the next list item</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Below is the script you should insert.

```
$('.grid .object').hide().filter(':lt(1)').show();
$('.show-next').click(function(){
   $eL = $('.grid .object').filter(":visible");
  //  $(".grid").find(".object").hide().next().show();
    if($eL.next().length>0){
              $eL.next().show();
          }else{
               $('.grid .object')[0].show();
          }
});
```