# Button click show den div hide prev div like slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, onclick

Hello I want to create something like slider when I click a button show the next div and hide the prev div with 3 divs.

HTML:

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
<div class="divs">
    <div>1</div>
    <div> 2</div>
    <div> 3</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
    $(".fa-chevron-right").click(function (e) {});
    $(".fa-chevron-left").click(function (e) {});
});
```

Comment: come on man...there are 1000's of slider scripts and tutorials out there. At least try something. The code shown does absolutely nothing and shows very little research effort

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery : how to show the next div and hide the present one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978491/jquery-how-to-show-the-next-div-and-hide-the-present-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish it with ease using jQuery's `next()`, `prev()` and `siblings()` methods. I spend five minutes writing some rough code.

http://jsfiddle.net/85kcffo9/1/

Hope it helps in you journey to learn jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <head>
   <style>
    .divControl
   {
       position:absolute;
       width: 80px;
       height: 80px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
       -moz-border-radius: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    </style>
   </head>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left">left</i></a>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right">right</i></a>
   <div class="divs"        
style="position:absolute;width:250px;height:80px;overflow:hidden;border: 3px #658958    solid;">
    <div id="wrapper" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;">
    <div class="divControl" style="left:0px;background:red">1</div>
    <div class="divControl" style="left:100px;background:blue"> 2</div>
    <div class="divControl" style="left:200px;background:green"> 3</div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <script>

      $(document).ready(function () {      
       $(".fa-chevron-right").click(function (e) {

       $( "#wrapper" ).animate({
       left: "+=70",
       opacity: 1
       }, 700 ); 

      });
      $(".fa-chevron-left").click(function (e) {

     $( "#wrapper" ).animate({
     left: "-=70",
     opacity: 1
    }, 700 );    

    });
     });
     </script>

     </body>
    </html>
```